# Accordo del verbo con il soggetto "alcuni di voi (noi)"

Tags: grammar, verbs, sentences, agreement

Non sono sicura su come si debba fare l'accordo del verbo in una frase il cui soggetto è "alcuni di voi" o "alcuni di noi". Il verbo si deve coniugare in seconda (o prima) persona plurale o in terza persona plurale?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Poiché il soggetto della frase "Alcuni di noi/voi [verbo]" è "Alcuni", mentre il pronome personale ("noi" o "voi") funge da complemento partitivo, è corretto coniugare il verbo alla terza persona plurale.

Comment: @randomatlabuser grazie :)